# C Arrays Not Retaining Values

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a simple Base64 decoding function in C. The output of this function looks correct (based on comparing the result with existing tools) when using the printf() debugging lines as below:

```
unsigned char * b64decode(char *line)
{
    char *idx;
    unsigned char *decode;
    int i,j,len,dlen,hold = 0;

    idx  = strchr(line, '\n');        //index of newline
    len  = idx - line;                //lenght of string
    dlen = 3 * (len / 4);             //decoded length

    decode = malloc((sizeof(unsigned char) * dlen) + 1);
    pad = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {      //deindex from ASCII
        line[i] = deindex(line[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0, j = u0; i < len; i++,j++) { 
        hold |= (line[i] << 18);  
        hold |= (line[++i] << 12);
        hold |= (line[++i] << 6);
        hold |= line[++i];

        decode[j] = hold >> 16;
        printf("%d ", decode[j]);
        decode[++j] = (hold >> 8) & 0xFF;
        printf("%d ", decode[j]);
        decode[++j] = hold & 0xFF;
        printf("%d ", decode[j]);

    hold = 0;
    }

    if (pad)                          //terminate before padding
        decode[dlen - pad] = '\0';

    return decode;

}
```

Which produces the (partial) output:

```
29 66 31 77 11 15 2 31 79 19 78 60 26 105 101 31 73 28 14 78 19 1 11 7 
78 27 1 22 69 54 0 30 1 73 100 32 84 29 29 67 51 83 78 101 82 6 0 71 84
28 13 69 77 7 4 12 83 18 60 12 30 8 73 26 9 17 79 20 76 33 26 71 43 0 5
29 71 89 17 4 9 0 100 38 7 83 0 55 22 6 12 26 23 65 29 1 82 84 48 95 0 32
19 10 5 71 79 18 72 8 69 78 101
```

The problem arises when I try to access this array after exiting the for loop with those printf() lines. This for loop (maximum i value is arbitrary) ...

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("%d ", decode[i]);
}
```

Produces this output...

```
29 66 31 77 11 15 2 31 79 19 78 60 26 105 101 31 73 28 14 78 19 1 11 7 78
27 1 22 69 54 0 30 1 73 100 32 84 29 29 67 51 83 78 101 82 6 0 71 84 28 
13 69 77 7 4 12 83 18 60 12 30 8 73 26 9 17 79 20 76 33 26 71 43 0 5 29
71 89 17 4 9 0 100 38 7 83 0 55 22 6 12 26 23 65 29 1 82 84 48 95 0 32 19
10 5 71 79 168 187 158 23 131 127 0 0 168 187 158 23 131 127 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 88 187 158 23 131 127 0 0 88 187 158 23 131 127
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 64 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 16 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 72 85 73 102
```

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show us actual working code.

Comment: What's `j = u0`?

Comment: Present a [mcve].  For what it's worth, though, it appears to me that the tail of the data must be clobbered outside the function you presented.

Comment: Do note, by the way, that base-64 can encode data containing null bytes.  It is not safe to assume that the whole decoded result can be handled as a unit with C string functions.

Comment: Only have a second to look at this.. but the first advice I would give is to look at your dlen calculation.  What if len / 4 is not an integer?  And you're incrementing j when you increment i in your loop.. you should be incrementing your input index `i` 1.5 times for every increment of `j`, not the other way around.. your index handling is all wrong.

Comment: Restrict i. Obviously you are going out of bounds. Last value that decode must have in this case is 32. Which is there, bit beyond that it is undefined behaviour. So expect anything beyond  that.

Answer (score 0):

OK folks, found the issue. The function as shown here works, the issue turned out to be with a realloc() called on *decode in error in the function which handles my function above. Fixing this produced the correct results.

Guess this is a swift lesson in providing more context!